# Kusto Custom Sort Order?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics

How do I perform a custom sort order in Kusto?

**Example query:**

```
//==================================================//
// Assign variables
//==================================================//
let varStart = ago(2d);
let varEnd = now();
let varStorageAccount = 'stgacctname';
//==================================================//
// Filter table
//==================================================//
StorageBlobLogs
| where TimeGenerated between (varStart .. varEnd)
  and AccountName == varStorageAccount
| sort by OperationName
```

**Need:**

- I want to put the various `OperationNames` (`GetBlob`, `AppendFile`, etc.) into a custom order.
- Something like:
  `| sort by OperationName['GetBlob'], OperationName['AppendFile'], OperationName asc`
- Ideally I'd like to specify values to sort by then allow Kusto to order the remaining using `asc`/`desc`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for your vote in another question. And about this case, kusto doesn't provide such kind of 'sort', so I think you may use union all the subquery result so that they can be custom sorted, I mean that `let a = Your Query|where OperationName='GetBlob' 
 sort by OperationName; let b = Your Query|where OperationName='AppendFile' 
 sort by OperationName; union a,b`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an aux column, like this:

```
datatable(OperationName:string, SomethingElse:string)
[
    "AppendFile", "3",
    "GetBlob", "1",
    "AppendFile", "4",
    "GetBlob", "2"
]
| extend OrderPriority =
    case(OperationName == "GetBlob", 1,
         OperationName == "AppendFile", 2,
         3)
| order by OrderPriority asc, SomethingElse asc 
| project-away OrderPriority
```

Output:

| OperationName | SomethingElse |
| --- | --- |
| GetBlob | 1 |
| GetBlob | 2 |
| AppendFile | 3 |
| AppendFile | 4 |

Comment: Sounds like this is not possible using raw Kusto. This is a good work around albeit a bit complex. Thank you.